# How does this cousin have NO relation to other cousin?

Tags: dna

My husband and two of his cousins had their DNA done.

Cousin A comes back as 1st cousin (as he should) cousin B comes back as distant 6th-8th cousin.

Cousin A and B have NO relation.

Cousin B also has no relations through they're mothers side (which is how they are related) how is this possible?

Also cousin B has no relation to husbands half sister (they're mothers is how they should be related).

How does cousin B have relation to my husband but no one else?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  We can give you better answers if you tell us what tests your family has taken and what company you purchased them from instead of saying you "had your DNA done".  You can use the edit link underneath your question to add to it.

Your question could also be improved by explaining more about how the various people are related (on paper) and saying how they match or don't match via DNA, instead of using the word "relation" for everything.

Comment: I think your question would benefit greatly by paying more attention to your terminology (as @JanMurphy commented) and by including a picture of how you think the tree branches linking the individuals should look from what you believe to be their genetic relationships.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit difficult to follow the description of how the various people are expected to be related, but as far as I can tell, you are talking about three people who were believed to all be biological first cousins of each other, at least before they had DNA tests: (1) your husband, (2) cousin A, (3) cousin B.

What the DNA tests said were that your husband and cousin A had a large amount of matching DNA, consistent with them being biological first cousins as expected.

But cousin B shares very little or no DNA with your husband or his half sister, both of whom were expected to be biological first cousins of B.

Given that evidence, the likely situation is that B's parent who is supposed to be your husband's biological aunt or uncle is not B's biological parent. (It's also unlikely that B shares one biological grandparent with your husband, since that would lead to them being half first cousins, with a much larger match than was observed.)

The fact that your husband shares a small amount of DNA with B -- 6th to 8th cousin according to the interpretation your testing service gave -- could either indicate that B is in fact distantly related to your husband, or it might just be random chance and not indicate any relationship.

Note that there is a very high chance that 6th-8th cousins share no DNA. As genetic genealogist CeCe Moore puts it:

"Fourth cousins will match each other about 50 percent of the time, but when you get out past the fifth-cousin level, the odds of sharing any DNA are less than 5 percent."

https://www.theroot.com/how-much-dna-do-distant-cousins-actually-share-1790877726

Comment: You're right https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/5263/peter-taylor - I had my logic wrong. I've rewritten that part.